# can not link css file to django

Tags: python, html, css, static-linking, django-staticfiles

This is html file where I linked the CSS file

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>ShairuFitness</title>

    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.7/js/all.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'fit/css/base.css' %}">
```

This is settings.py file

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILE_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static'),]
```

This is location of file

```
static
 ->fit
   ->css
     ->base.css
```

ERROR

```
[10/Aug/2020 20:50:31] "GET /static/fit/css/base.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1674
```

Comment: Did you run `manage.py collectstatic`?

Comment: No, i didn't actually i am a beginner in django and didn't have to use this command in previous chapters

Comment: Even after running that i am still getting the same error!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this settings:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

The `STATIC_ROOT` is used to set up the path to your static files. Your can read more on [the official doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#static-root).

Comment: It was a typo, Thanks a lot for helping.